# Dusk error (element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other Element would receive the click. [FIX]

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, laravel-dusk

I have an error in my Laravel Dusk browser (i.e. integrated) test that often occurs on Travis CI and cannot easily reproduce locally:

> Element is not clickable at point (x, y) Other element would receive the click."

This is sometimes caused by checkbox labels or by the element being off-screen and needing to be scrolled to, but this wasn't the case in my issue.

In my case, I have a custom dropdown made of divs. When I try and click `.dropdown__item` that's wrapped in a div `.dropdown`, the `.dropdown` wrapper div receives the click instead.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should move your fix into an answer instead of adding it to the question, it's not very clear that it is a fix for those quickly scanning for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

*Since it's been almost a year without the OP moving their fix into an answer and since I've twice almost clicked away from this question without realising the solution is in the question itself, I decided to move it into an answer.*

---

The fix for this issue is to stop propagation on the `dropdown__item`. In Vue 2 that is simply `@click.stop="methodName"`, but in vanilla JS it would be `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

This was a long-standing problem for me while using `scrollIntoView()` to scroll an element button into view to be clicked, but adding the `--disable-smooth-scrolling` option to `DuskTestCase.php` seems to have fixed it permanently:

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
    "--window-size=1920,1080",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--disable-smooth-scrolling" // add this
])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
    return $items->merge([
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--headless",
    ]);
})->all());
```